# calling the protocol methods in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, protocols

i have used the following protocol in the yyyy.h file of a class

```
 @protocol FGalleryViewControllerDelegate

    @required
    - (int)numberOfPhotosForPhotoGallery:(FGalleryViewController*)gallery;
    - (FGalleryPhotoSourceType)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController*)gallery sourceTypeForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

    @optional
    - (NSString*)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController*)gallery captionForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

    // the photosource must implement one of these methods depending on which FGalleryPhotoSourceType is specified 
    - (NSString*)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController*)gallery filePathForPhotoSize:(FGalleryPhotoSize)size atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
    - (NSString*)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController*)gallery urlForPhotoSize:(FGalleryPhotoSize)size atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

    @end
```

and i am calling these methods using the delegate object

```
NSObject < FGalleryViewControllerDelegate> *_photoSource;
```

in some other class not in yyy.m,,

now i tried to call these methods in the same class yyy.m,,i used the same delegate object to call the methods but its crashed ,,should i use self to call those?

Comment: where u calling this method try using this object.delegate = self; or wahtever

Comment: Create property of this delegate

Comment: ya i have already have it ,like this  @property (nonatomic,assign) NSObject<FGalleryViewControllerDelegate> *_photoSource;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want self to call those then set the @property of this delegate object. and then use it it works.

Comment: ya i have already have it ,like this @property (nonatomic,assign) NSObject<FGalleryViewControllerDelegate> *_photoSource;